# × Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app-compat/no-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

here is where i am getting the error:

```
import {Button, ThemeProvider} from "@mui/material";

import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebase/compat/auth"

const auth = firebase.auth();

function LoginForm(props) {

    function loginHandler() {

    }

    function loginWithGoogleHandler() {
        const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
    }

    return (

        <ThemeProvider theme={props.theme}>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={loginHandler}>
                LOGIN
            </Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={loginWithGoogleHandler}>
                LOGIN WITH GOOGLE?
            </Button>
        </ThemeProvider>

    );

}

export default LoginForm;
```

It does not say which line the error is one. I looked up some other solutions and they said that you were defining something before the other thing but i didnt understand it very well and those solutions contained `const db = firebase.firestore();` so i think its something else that is wrong with my code.

Comment: Most of those other solutions should have a call to `initializeApp()`, which the error message also refers to and which is missing from your code.

Comment: Do you need an `initializeApp()` for every file that you use firebase in? I just put it in my App.js.

Comment: It' not about files, but about the application that runs. Every time you access Firebase on a new page, some call to `initializeApp` needs to happen before you can use Firebase - otherwise you get the error you have.